# An $n \times n$ matrix $M$ of integers has the property that $M_{ab} = M_{xy}$ iff $a+b=x+y$. How many distinct elements are there in $M$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

An $n \times n$ matrix $M$ of integers has the property that $M_{ab} = M_{xy}$ iff $a+b=x+y$. How many distinct elements are there in $M$?

Answer (score 4):

$a+b$ is constant on every anti-diagonal, of which there are $2n-1$, so there are $2n-1$ distinct elements.

Comment: Why is it 2n-1 distinct elements, should it be n. I was checking over  my answer.Since the diagonal will only contain the distinct elements

Comment: There are $n$ anti-diagonals that cross the main diagonal and $n-1$ anti-diagonals that pass through it without crossing, in total $2n-1$ anti-diagonals. Another way to think about it is that the sum $a+b$ is anything from $2$ to $2n$, where each such number corresponds to a diagonal. There are $2n-1$ numbers in that range.